# Communication between two WPF applications

Tags: wpf, wcf, .net-4.0, communication

I have two WPF applications, I need these two applications to be able to communicate with each other. I just need these applications to send some notifications to each other and nothing more. I have found two techniques yet, one is using WCF, and another is using DDE. But to me these seems too much complicated for my requirement. Please suggest what is the simplest way to go about this? What other options I have?

Comment: Depends. Do these notifications have attached data? How do your apps identify each other? Does one have the other's PID? Does it have a HWND to the other's main window?

Comment: As I said there is nothing more than just notifying other one of some event. There is no attached data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they are both on the same network(otherwise you need to port foward the port that you use), you could make a TCP connection between them, both need a TCPlistener and a TCP client. This is easy to createre: here is a small [tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1415/Introduction-to-TCP-client-server-in-C)

Comment: Thanks Maximc, that helped me out.